# Create index column reverse group by column

Tags: r

I want to create a column sequenced like rank but not based on numerical values.
like in the example below.

```r
a <- rep(letters[1:3],each =3)
b <- round(rnorm(9,5,1),2)
tempdf <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
tempdf
#>   a    b
#> 1 a 5.58
#> 2 a 3.68
#> 3 a 5.12
#> 4 b 3.28
#> 5 b 4.97
#> 6 b 6.57
#> 7 c 5.92
#> 8 c 5.25
#> 9 c 3.02
tempdf["c"] <- rep(1:3, each = 3)
tempdf
#>   a    b c
#> 1 a 5.58 1
#> 2 a 3.68 1
#> 3 a 5.12 1
#> 4 b 3.28 2
#> 5 b 4.97 2
#> 6 b 6.57 2
#> 7 c 5.92 3
#> 8 c 5.25 3
#> 9 c 3.02 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

My data actually looks more like this. I want to create an index of week number over multiple years. Please suggest better ways to do it.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

a <- seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-02-28"), by = "1 day")
b <- round(rnorm(59,5,1),2)
tempdf <- cbind.data.frame(a,b)
tempdf <- tempdf %>% 
mutate(weeks = week(a), 
       month = month(a),
       year = year(a)) %>% 
    # mutate(ymw = 10000*year+100*month+weeks) %>%
    mutate(ymw = paste0(year,month, weeks)) 
tempdf
#>             a    b weeks month year    ymw
#> 1  2021-01-01 6.78     1     1 2021 202111
#> 2  2021-01-02 4.17     1     1 2021 202111
#> 3  2021-01-03 5.65     1     1 2021 202111
#> 4  2021-01-04 5.20     1     1 2021 202111
#> 5  2021-01-05 4.55     1     1 2021 202111
#> 6  2021-01-06 5.07     1     1 2021 202111
#> 7  2021-01-07 6.29     1     1 2021 202111
#> 8  2021-01-08 6.01     2     1 2021 202112
#> 9  2021-01-09 4.45     2     1 2021 202112
#> 10 2021-01-10 5.35     2     1 2021 202112
#> 11 2021-01-11 5.10     2     1 2021 202112
#> 12 2021-01-12 4.34     2     1 2021 202112
#> 13 2021-01-13 4.47     2     1 2021 202112
#> 14 2021-01-14 6.03     2     1 2021 202112
#> 15 2021-01-15 6.55     3     1 2021 202113
#> 16 2021-01-16 5.60     3     1 2021 202113
#> 17 2021-01-17 5.54     3     1 2021 202113
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options, depending on what you ultimately intend to do with the column.

```
tempdf %>% 
  mutate(
    weekIndex_1 = year + weeks/100,
    weekIndex_2 = floor(as.numeric(a)/7)
  )
#>             a    b weeks month year    ymw weekIndex_1 weekIndex_2
#> 1  2021-01-01 7.30     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2661
#> 2  2021-01-02 4.53     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2661
#> 3  2021-01-03 5.21     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2661
#> 4  2021-01-04 6.74     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2661
#> 5  2021-01-05 4.53     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2661
#> 6  2021-01-06 5.56     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2661
#> 7  2021-01-07 5.09     1     1 2021 202111     2021.01        2662
#> 8  2021-01-08 4.82     2     1 2021 202112     2021.02        2662
#> 9  2021-01-09 5.65     2     1 2021 202112     2021.02        2662
#> 10 2021-01-10 4.46     2     1 2021 202112     2021.02        2662
```

Both will allow you to sort on the index. The difference is `weekIndex_1` tracks the year and resets the week number when the year changes. In a sense, using semantic versioning for the date. This is very similar to what you did with the `ymw` column though. With `weekIndex_2` you are essentially tracking years since the origin, which accounts for the fact that years aren't exactly 52 weeks long. You get the sequential order, but lose a bit of the year context. Since you have both these in other columns already (`weeks` and `year`), perhaps this isn't that important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a way. what I am really looking for is a way to create something like a `seq_along(by)`, or something like `row_number()`, `'index` or something, which is more general than just dealing dates and weeks.